# How do I run mercurial queries from C++ (cross-platform)?

Tags: c++, c, api, mercurial

I would like to run some mercurial queries from C++ and get some results (similar to what we get on the command line) and would like it to be cross-platform. Any way to accomplish this without using [Mercurial python API](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MercurialApi) (I am hoping to see a wrapper that someone has already built in C++ or in C)?

Answer (score 2):

Better than using the python API would be interfacing with the [Mercurial Command Server](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer) though it does not yet have a C / C++ wrapper.

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommandServer#Libraries